# SwiftUI: onCommit triggered when is when I click away rather than press Return

Tags: textview, swiftui, keystroke

I am working with onCommit for a text view in SwiftUI (the app is for MacOS).

```
struct TextBlockView: View {
     @State private var content = ""
    var id = UUID()

       var body: some View {

        let block = MacEditorTextView(text: $content, onEditingChanged: {
            print("editing changed")
        }, onCommit: {
            Keystroke.keystroke.enterPressed = true
            print("add new textblock here")
            //trigger function to create next block
           }).multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
               .frame(minWidth: 300,
                      maxWidth: .infinity,
                      minHeight: 40,
                      maxHeight: .infinity)
                .focusable()

        let tag = Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.init(red: 1.00, green: 0.95, blue: 0.80, opacity: 1))
                    .frame(width: 10, height: 10)


        return HStack {
            tag
            block
        }
       }
}
```

The desired action occurs when the user clicks away from the text block (a new textblock is added). However, I would like this action to occur when the user hits return. It worked this way for about 30 minutes when I first wrote the code for onCommit, before it decided a commit was a click rather than press of the return key.

I have tried to use the "onCommand" instead of onCommit, but this did not work, and I am unsure if I used the appropriate selector. I have also tried to capture when the enter key is pressed at the level of the NSWindow. However, I decided this was not desired, as I do not wish for this action to take place whenever the enter key is pressed.

Any help in relating onCommit to a specific key (return) would be very appreciated.

I am new to StackOverflow, so let me know if more information is needed.

Comment: It does not happen with standard `TextField`, so I assume it is in used `MacEditorTextView`. Would you show code for it?

Comment: The MacEditorTextView is actually a wrapper on an NSTextView so that it can be used for SwiftUI. It can be found here: https://gist.github.com/unnamedd/6e8c3fbc806b8deb60fa65d6b9affab0 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my issue not by using onCommit, but rather including this function in the NSTextView wrapper:

```
        func textView(_ textView: NSTextView, doCommandBy commandSelector: Selector) -> Bool {
             if (commandSelector == #selector(NSResponder.insertNewline(_:))) {
                            // Do something against ENTER key
                            print("enter")
                            //triggers function to create next block.
                            Keystroke.keystroke.enterPressed = true
                            return true
                        } else if (commandSelector == #selector(NSResponder.deleteForward(_:))) {
                            // Do something against DELETE key
                            return true
                        } else if (commandSelector == #selector(NSResponder.deleteBackward(_:))) {
                            // Do something against BACKSPACE key
                            return true
                        } else if (commandSelector == #selector(NSResponder.insertTab(_:))) {
                            // Do something against TAB key
                            return true
                        } else if (commandSelector == #selector(NSResponder.cancelOperation(_:))) {
                            // Do something against ESCAPE key
                            return true
                        }
            return false
        }
```

Note, this was written in a coordinator that conformed to the NSTextViewDelegate and NSControlTextEditingDelegate protocols. I'm not exactly sure which one specifically caused it to work.

If anyone faces this issue in the future and stumbles upon this post, do not hesitate to reach out to me.

Comment: Would love it if you could expand on this method - not sure how to implement it with SwiftUI. I'm getting sick of the way swift for MacOS is the second class citizen, missing UI features and bugs everywhere.

Comment: Hi! I'm also very very very sick of it, and feeling your pain. I stuck this function into my NSTextViewDelegate coordinator class. This class also conformed to the NSControlTextEditingDelegate protocol, which my be necessary for it to work. Hope that helps?

Comment: Hi, I ended up publishing the TextField view with @Published and then used the combine framework with cancellable, sink and debounce to run the function I needed.  It's a pain because publishers emit before the value changes and therefore the function runs on launch - before other variables like a token from an api ;) are set. I made the function conditional so it only runs if the token is valid but that seems like a hack.  Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement something like this. When you click on the blue box, it sends a single to say you have. Put the box behind your text box.

Cut'n'Pasted this quickly, a lot more code than you really need, you can do some pruning to this answer too.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

let saidNDone = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    Example1()
}
}

struct Example1: View {
@State var viewState: CGSize = .zero
@State var dragState: CGSize = .zero
@State var touched = false

var body: some View {
    let dragGesture = DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: CoordinateSpace.global)
        .onChanged { (value) in
            self.dragState = value.translation
    }.onEnded { (value) in
        self.viewState.width += value.translation.width
        self.viewState.height += value.translation.height
        self.dragState = .zero
        saidNDone.send()
    }
    return VStack {
        Rectangle().foregroundColor(.blue).frame(width: 100, height: 100)
        .offset(x: dragState.width + viewState.width,
                y: dragState.height + viewState.height)
        .gesture(dragGesture)
        Text("Hello World ")
          .onReceive(saidNDone) { ( _ ) in
            self.touched = true
          }
        .foregroundColor(self.touched ? Color.red: Color.black)
    }
}
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
}
}
```

Comment: Hello, perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but would this send a signal on clicking? I want to trigger an action (or receive a signal) when the Enter/Return key is pressed on the user's keyboard.

Comment: Yes, it will send multiple signals on clicking